# Java records validation fail when using byte buddy

Tags: java, bean-validation, byte-buddy, java-record

So i'm trying to do validation of java records as its done  [in this article](https://www.morling.dev/blog/enforcing-java-record-invariants-with-bean-validation/)

I have a custom validator for validating phone number that uses google's phone number library and i'm getting the following error when I try to build and when I run the validation tests the validation is ignored and it fails.

```
Failed to execute goal net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-maven-plugin:1.12.9:transform (default) on project deposits: 
Failed to transform class files in deposits-api/target/classes: 
None of public static void com.validations.RecordValidationInterceptor.validate(java.lang.reflect.Constructor,java.lang.Object[])
allows for delegation from 
public com.models.OnlinePaymentRequest(java.lang.String,java.math.BigDecimal,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int)
```

model

```
public record OnlinePaymentRequest(
    @JsonProperty("transactionId")
    @NotBlank(message = "transactionId Value cannot be null or blank")
    String transactionId,
    
    @JsonProperty("amount")
    @DecimalMax("70000.00")
    BigDecimal amount,
    
    @JsonProperty("msisdn")
    @KEPhoneNumber
    String msisdn,
    
    @JsonProperty("paybill")
    @NotBlank(message = "paybill Value cannot be null or blank")
    String paybill,
    
    @JsonProperty("accountReference")
    @NotNull(message = "accountReference Value cannot be null")
    String accountReference,
    
    @JsonProperty("userId")
    @Positive(message = "userId Value cannot be a negative number")
    int userId) {
  
}
```

validator plugin and interceptor classes

```
public class RecordValidationPlugin implements Plugin{

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescription target) {
        return target.getDeclaredMethods()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(m -> m.isConstructor() && isConstrained(m));
    }

    @Override
    public Builder<?> apply(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassFileLocator classFileLocator) {
        return builder.constructor(this::isConstrained)
                .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.andThen(
                        MethodDelegation.to(RecordValidationInterceptor.class)));
    }

    private boolean isConstrained(MethodDescription method) {
        return hasConstrainedReturnValue(method) || hasConstrainedParameter(method);
    }

    private boolean hasConstrainedReturnValue(MethodDescription method) {
        return !method.getDeclaredAnnotations()
                .asTypeList()
                .filter(hasAnnotation(annotationType(Constraint.class)))
                .isEmpty();
    }

    private boolean hasConstrainedParameter(MethodDescription method) {
        return method.getParameters()
                .asDefined()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(p -> isConstrained(p));
    }

    private boolean isConstrained(ParameterDescription.InDefinedShape parameter) {
        return !parameter.getDeclaredAnnotations()
                .asTypeList()
                .filter(hasAnnotation(annotationType(Constraint.class)))
                .isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
    }
}

public class RecordValidationInterceptor {

    private static final Validator VALIDATOR;

    static {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        VALIDATOR = factory.getValidator();
    }

    public static <T> void validate(@Origin Constructor<T> constructor, @AllArguments Object[] args) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = VALIDATOR.forExecutables()
                .validateConstructorParameters(constructor, args);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            String message = violations.stream()
                    .map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(message, violations);
        }
    }

}
```

custom validator

```
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = KEPhoneNumberValidator.class)
public @interface KEPhoneNumber {
    public String message() default "Invalid phone number.";
    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};
     public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
public class KEPhoneNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<KEPhoneNumber, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(KEPhoneNumber constraintAnnotation) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        LOGGER.info("validating phone number: "+value+" ........");
        return isMsisdnValid(value);
    }
    
    public static boolean isMsisdnValid(String msisdn) {
        PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        boolean isValid = false;
        try {
            Phonenumber.PhoneNumber kenyaNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(msisdn, "KE");
            isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(kenyaNumberProto);
        } catch (NumberParseException e) {
            LOGGER.info("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    
}
```

the test

```
@Test
    public void canValidateOnlinePaymentReQuest() throws Exception {
        OnlinePaymentRequest valid = new OnlinePaymentRequest("WIWU87v3XXHT", BigDecimal.ONE, "254725909090", "3009809", "USER-001", 4);
        System.out.println(valid);

        try {
            OnlinePaymentRequest invalid = new OnlinePaymentRequest(null, BigDecimal.ONE, "", "3009809", "USER-001", -10);
            System.out.println(invalid);
            fail("Expected ConstraintViolationException not thrown");
        }
        catch(ConstraintViolationException cve) {
            System.out.println(cve.getMessage());
            assertEquals(3, cve.getConstraintViolations().size());
        }
    }
```

Comment: should be good now

Comment: Can you check your imports? It is important that you import annotations from the *bind* package and not those of *Advice*.

Comment: yes indeed that was the issue.  the @AllArguments import was from advice changed to bind and its working thanks.